# How to use "Intl.DateTimeFormat" in nextjs react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

my component is rendering at the server so "Intl.DateTimeFormat" is accesible available.

how do i use "Intl.DateTimeFormat" in nextjs react component?

the error:

```
Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is usually that `Intl.DateTimeFormat` gives slightly different results when run on the server vs when run in the browser: e.g., server `"8 feb."` vs client: `"8 feb"`.

It seems that you use the `pages` router, so to easily debug the issue, you can wrap your complete app in a suspense boundary.

I see 3 approaches for solving the issue:

1. Use a library like `date-fns` for formatting the dates
2. Render the component only server-side (would require you to switch to `app` router)
3. Render the component only client-side 
   To do this, I'd suggest creating a `ClientBoundary` component and wrapping the component that renders the date string with it:

```
"use client";
import { type ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function ClientBoundary({
  children,
  fallback = null,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
  fallback?: ReactNode;
}) {
  const [client, setClient] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => setClient(true), []);
  return <>{client ? children : fallback}</>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Intl.DateTimeFormat in your Next.js React component by importing the Intl API from the JavaScript standard library. You can then call the Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor, passing in the locale and the desired format options.

For example:

```
import { Intl } from 'intl'

// ...

const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
  day: '2-digit',
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric'
});

// ...

<p>Date: {dateFormatter.format(new Date())}</p>
```